# Is there a hook that will be called before each database read?

Tags: hooks

I'm trying to get a little more familiar with writing extensions. I am still struggling with finding the correct / most specific hook function for my patches regularly.

As a specific example, I am altering an SQL call in sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Case/BAO/Case.php::getCaseActivity().
So if I want to create an extension for that, I would need a hook function that will be called whenever sth is read from a database table. I checked all the hooks in https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/ but couldn't find a suitable one.

Is there a hook function like that? Is there a more specific alternative to save resources (checking the hook extension each time a database table is called would happen lots of times)?

Can I create custom hook "call points" to determine at which line of code a hook is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no hook for reading data from the database. There are hooks however for rendering [forms](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/list/#form-hooks) and [pages](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/list/#gui-hooks).

There is also a hook for api v3 which is called before and after each api call. That hook is called [apiWrapper](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_apiWrappers/)

Comment: As you said there is a hook for reading data from the database - can you tell me which one?

Comment: I believe Jaap dropped a word "no".  There isn't a hook for reading data from the database.  Such a hook would be near impossible to write, because unlike writing to the database, reading the database can happen in many ways - viewing a contact, doing a search, running a report, etc.